# Loading certain data in combobox based on textbox input

Tags: c#, event-handling

Based on gender, I want to load certain criteria.
For example, if I type 0 in a `textbox`, I want to load Mr., Dr. , etc..
If I type 1, I want to load Ms, Mrs, Miss, Dr. etc...
How can I do so?
Gender is typed in a `textbox`, and I want the `combo box` to load what I specified above. 
Thank you.

Comment: What platform are you running on? Windows Forms? WPF? Web?

Comment: In what technology? asp.net winform, wpf, silverlight...?

Comment: offtopic but still Do you mean gender would be captured as `0,1 ....` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just Sudo code there must be typo or Syntax error but you need to do something as below :

```
    List<string> strMale = new List<string>{"Mr.", "Dr. "};
    List<string> strFMale = new List<string>{"Mrs.", "Miss"};

//make use of Textbox Change Event
public void Text1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

  Combo1.Items.Clear();

  //Bind the values using the text box input value 
  if(Text1.Text=="0")
   {
     Combo1.DataSource = strMale ;
   }
   else if(Text1.Text=="1")
   {
     Combo1.DataSource = strFMale ;
   }
  Combo1.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: in second if statements need to change to `== "1"`

Comment: Is there something other than datasource that can be used? The logic makes sense 100% :D

Comment: @Adrian - other than datasoruce you can push item directly as suggested by kalyan.... one more thing this datasource may be form database or hardcoded as i did

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle event ValueChanged (the name of the event depends on platform you're working with) and depending on value typed change source of your combobox

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Code Use can use [comboBox.Items.Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19fc31ss%28VS.80%29.aspx) or [comboBox.Items.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19fc31ss%28VS.80%29.aspx) for inserting new items into a combobox.

```
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox2.Text == "0")
            {
                if (comboBox1.Items.Count > 0)
                      comboBox1.Items.Clear();
                comboBox1.Items.Insert(0,"Mr");
                comboBox1.Items.Insert(1, "Dr");
            }
            else if (textBox2.Text == "1")
            {
                if (comboBox1.Items.Count > 0)
                      comboBox1.Items.Clear();
                comboBox1.Items.Add("Ms");
                comboBox1.Items.Add("Mrs");
                comboBox1.Items.Add("Miss");
            }
        }
```

Comment: What's the difference between Insert and Add?

Comment: Using `Insert` we can insert a particular item at what ever index we want to insert, where as using `Add` we can't insert at a selective index, the items will by default adds from `0` index.